# Variaveis globais diferentes que quando uma é alterada muda o valor em todas

Tags: array, python-3.x, variáveis, arraylist

Tenho uma classe responsável por gerenciar determinadas variáveis chamadas `clusters`, esses são um `vetor de vetores` ontem contém uma palavra e um valor associado. Porém toda vez que faço um ajuste no valor associado esse valor é alterado em todos os outros clusters (`que são variáveis globais`).

Dentro dessa classe existem três métodos um deles `Find_palavra` que recebe como parâmetro uma frase que vai analisar se esta já existe em nos clusters criados. Tem o `add_palavra` pega um palavra e adiciona em todos os clusters e o `Ajust_Cluster` que soma um valor na palavra.

Precisa existir vários clusters por que `determinadas palavras precisam assumir valores diferentes em situações diferentes`, para poder ter essa flexibilidade o valor alterado em um cluster precisa ficar só nele sem ser espelhado em todos os outros.

**Existe um variável também global chamada `data` que contém todas as palavras dos clusters porém com os valores associados zerados.

```
class Clustering:
def Find_palavra(frase):
    global data
    i=0
    x=0
    controle=0
    palavras=frase.split(' ')
    while(len(palavras)>i):
        if(str(palavras[i]) in data):
            controle=1                
        if(controle==0):
            Clustering.add_palavra(palavras[i])
        i=i+1


def add_palavra(palavra):
    global data
    global cluster1
    global cluster2
    global cluster3
    global cluster4
    global cluster5
    global cluster6
    global cluster7
    global cluster8
    global cluster9
    global cluster10
    global cluster11

    array=[]
    array.append(palavra)
    array.append(0)
    data.append(array)
    cluster1.append(array)
    cluster2.append(array)
    cluster3.append(array)
    cluster4.append(array)
    cluster5.append(array)
    cluster6.append(array)
    cluster7.append(array)
    cluster8.append(array)
    cluster9.append(array)
    cluster10.append(array)
    cluster11.append(array)
    i=i+1

#parametro res é as palavras que precisam ser alteradas no cluster se as palavras estiverem em res é somado em seu valor associado se não é diminuido.
def Ajust_Cluster(palavras,res,cluster,p):

    global data
    global cluster1
    global cluster2
    global cluster3
    global cluster4
    global cluster5
    global cluster6
    global cluster7
    global cluster8
    global cluster9
    global cluster10
    global cluster11
    k=0
    i=0
    w=0
    difer=(1/1)
    words=res.split(' ')
    while(len(words)>k):
        i=0
        while((len(cluster))>i):
            if(words[k]==cluster[i][0]):
                cluster[i][1]=float(cluster[i][1])+difer
            i=i+1
        k=k+1
    while((len(cluster)-1)>w):
        if(cluster[w][0] in words):
            pass
        else:
            T=randint(1,2)
            if(T==1):
                cluster[w][1]=float(cluster[w][1])-difer
        w=w+1

    print("Valor alterado:",cluster)

    if(300>palavras and palavras>230):
        cluster10=cluster


    elif(230>palavras and palavras>200):
        cluster11=cluster
```

Comment: Acho este código muito confuso e se simplificá-lo será mais fácil mexer nisto, seja lá o que está querendo fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está entendendo bem alguns conceitos de estruturas de dados aí, e o seu programa fica confuso. Vou tentar dar umas dicas, mas é importante você fazer uma pausa e digerir bem - de preferência indo para o modo interativo do Python e fazendo algumas operações de "tentativa e erro" até entender bem as coisas.

Não sei nem se consigo escrever em ordem de importância.

- **o que está gerando seu erro**: Um objeto em Python é criado quando você o constrói - seja chamando sua classe, seja usando um literal como `[]` (que cria uma lista vazia). Você dá nomes para os objetos - esses nomes nós chamamos de variáveis. Quando você aponta uma outra variável para o mesmo objeto, ou coloca o mesmo objeto em várias listas diferentes, ou dicionários-  ainda é o mesmo objeto. Você tem referências pra ele em vários lugares. No seu código você cria uma única lista vazia com o nome de `array`, inicializa a mesma com alguns dados, e insere *essa uma mesma lista* em todos os seus "clusters". Quando essa lista sofre uma alteração, seja qual foi a forma que você chegou nela (se foi direto pela variável "array", se foi por um dos "clusters"), você altera aquela lista - a alteração vai ser visível não importa se você recupere a lista do "cluster1" ou do "cluster11", vai ser a mesma lista. Python tem operador `is` que verifica se você tem referências para o mesmo objeto - se vocẽ fizer no final do seu método add palavra a comparação com `is` de array com o último elemento inserido em qualquer um dos clusters, vai ver que retorna "True". E se alterar o "array", vai ver a mudança refletida em todos os clusters (que é o "problema" que você relatou). **como resolver isso pontualmente**: Adicione em cada cluster uma *cópia* da lista original, de nome `array`, não ela mesma. Você pode criar uma cópia importando o módulo `copy` do Python e usando a função `copy`:

  import copy

  ...
      def add_palavra(...):
          ...
          cluster1.append(copy.copy(array))

No caso específico de listas, você não precisa do `copy.copy` para fazer uma cópia - a operação de recuperar um índice com fatias pode fazer isso - você pega uma "fatia" que vai do primeiro ao último elemento da lista (basta deixar em branco os índices de início e fim da fatia em volta dos `:`) como em: `cluster1.append(array[:])`.

É vital que antes de você continuar seu programa você vá num prompt interativo do Python, crie uma variável com uma lista, ponha a lista em outra variável e outras estruturas de dados, pona cópias da lista em outras variáveis, e experimente com o operador `is` e a função `id`. *Nada* va i substituir uns 40 minutos brincando com isso:

```
Exemplo: 

In [1]: a = []

In [2]: b = a

In [3]: c = a[:]

In [4]: a.append("teste")

In [5]: a
Out[5]: ['teste']

In [6]: b
Out[6]: ['teste']

In [7]: c
Out[7]: []

In [8]: id(a), id(b), id(c)
Out[8]: (140510059971000, 140510059971000, 140510060067080)
```

- Segunda coisa: "listas" em Python são "listas". Chama-las de array não é uma boa prática e podem confundir você  - "array" é melhor utlizado para uma estrutura de dados que tenha elementos de tamanho uniforme, um em sequência do outro na memóra, e tamanho "mais ou menos" fixo (embora possa ser alterado). As listas em Python são compostas de objetos de qualquer tipo, e fundamentalmente podem mudar de tamanho.
- Terceira coisa: variáveis globais não são em geral uma boa prática. Eu sou um autor controverso porque defendo o seu uso em vários contextos - uma vez que em Python elas são isoladas nos módulos (tem "namespace"), mas a forma que você está usando realmente é ruim.
- Quarta coisa: Se você tem uma lista ou outro objeto mutável numa variável, não precisa declarar esse objeto como `global` numa função em que vai mexer *dentro* desse objeto. Só precisa disso se vai reatribuir a variável a outro objeto. Ou seja - no seu caso, como os "clusters" já estão criados fora dos seus métodos, e você só vai adiconar elementos dentro dos mesmos, não precisa desse monte de declaração `global` em cada função. Em Python uma variável global é acessada para leitura normalmente de dentro de uma função - quando você acessa a variável, o Python te retorna o objeto ao qual ela se refere (no caso, listas) - e você opera nessas listas.

Ou seja:

`cluster1.append("teste")` não precisa que cluster1 seja declarado como global na função. Já `cluster1 = ["teste"]` precisa -nesse caso um novo objeto do tipo lista é criado e associado à variável.

- quinta coisa - mas talvez a mais importante,e de vesse estar primeiro: A tarefa mais importante que os computadores fazem é poder repetir tarefas milhares de vezes. Você parece se esquecer disso ao criar 11 variáveis praticamente idênticas, sem nem um nome distinto e repetir dezenas de vezes as mesmas linhas ao lidar com elas. Você só precisa de uma variável `clusters` - ela mesma uma lista (possivelmente será melhor um dicionário) - e em cada ponto que você tiver que fazer uma operação em todos os clusters, usar um `for`. Em cada ponto que for atuar sobre um cluster específico, usar o índice do mesmo. (Por isso pode ser melhor um dicionário, os clusters podem ser identificados por nomes mais significicativos que números de "1" a "11".).

COm essas consderações, seu método `add_palavra` fica sendo apenas:

```
# Cria 11 listas distintas  a serem usadas comoclusters:

clusters = [[] for _ in range(11)]  

class Clustering:

    def add_palavra(palavra):

        array=[]

        array.append(palavra)
        array.append(0)
        data.append(array[:])
        for cluster in clusters:
            cluster.append(array[:])
```

- sexta coisa:  Aqui você está associando uma palavra e um número usando uma lista de 2 elementos - parece uma ideia   ruim  e provavelmente você deveria estar usando um dicionário em vez de uma lista de listas de 2 elementos. Ou seja, em vez de ter uma estrutura como `[['palavra1', 2], ['palavra2', 0]]` que você vai ter que percorrer linearmente para achar cada palavra correspondente, use direto um dicionário:  `{'palavra1': 2, 'palavra2': 0}` - Em Python dicionários tem sua chave encontrada em tempo constante pela linguagem,e  você não precisa "programar" a busca de uma chave e alteração de seu valor.  Da mesma forma que referências ao mesmo objeto, é importante você brincar com dicionários no prompt interativo até entende-los. (e se for usar dicionários só para armazenar o número de ocorrências de cada palavra, verifique a estrutura [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) - ela provê diversas facilidades para isso)

Então - pra começar as dicas são essas - é fundamental que você entenda o que está acontecendo, e não faça só as mudanças que indiquei.

Comment: Vou aderir a todas as dicas e estudar os pontos apresentados. Muito obrigado mesmo por me informar todos os pontos que devo melhorar! :D